# I have some errors when I try to use /ngx ionic packages

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, rxjs

I want to use firebase or fcm getToken of device but `Object (...) is not a function` error appear.

I tried to install rxjs@6.0.0 and rxjs-compat@6.2.2 but it still doesn't work.

Ionic 4.12.0
Angular 5.2.11
Typescript 2.7.2

[image]

Comment: Please add the full error stack trace.

Comment: I've edited my post to show you the full stack trace